# Toggle between images using shorthand if

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are 2 images and a variable.

```
var score = '0';
<div class="parent">
  <id ="trophy" src="imageTrophy.jpg" style="display:none"/>
  <id ="progressing" src="imageprogress1.jpg"/>
</div>
```

How write a if statement shorthand to toggle between these 2 images depending on the score?

```
score == 10 ? $('.parent').find('img').toggle() : $('.parent').find('img').toggle();
```

Comment: (score == '10') ? $('#win').show() $('score').hide() : $('#win').hide() $('score').show();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
$('.parent').find('img').hide().eq(score == 10 ? 0 : 1).show();
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks good. Can you explain what `0 : 1` do?

Comment: that is index numbers like `.eq(0), .eq(1)`.

Comment: `.eq()` will act like fetching an element from an array. `.eq(0)` will fetch the first element.

Comment: `$('.parent').find('img').toggle(score == 10)` is it also?

Comment: @Jai But OP want to display single image all the time based on the score. It will either display both or hide the both. Right?

Comment: get it @RajaprabhuAravindasamy.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to change HTML, Use single `img` element and set its `src` on the basis of condition.

```
<div class="parent">
  <img src="" />
</div>
```

*Script*, It will set the 'src' property of `img` based on `score` variable value.

```
var score = '0';
$('.parent img').prop('src' , function(){
    return score == 10 ? 'imageTrophy.jpg' : 'imageprogress1.jpg';
});
```

Comment: Thanks and that's great. But I need to toggle loaded images.

Comment: @Becky, You may try `$('.parent').find('img:first').toggle(score == 10).end().find('img:last').toggle(score == 10)`